# jQuery UI Button with overflow

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have two nested containers, each with a height and overflow specified.  This usually works as expected, except when my inner container contains jQuery UI buttons.  When this is the case, it "looks" correct, but the outer container still scrolls, as if the content were visible, even though the it's being hidden by the inner container.

See this jsFiddle for a demonstration of the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/bnT2r/1/

Has anyone seen this before, or can come up with a solution to this issue?

**UPDATE:**
This only appears to be an issue in Chrome.  Tested in FF and IE8, and it appears as expected.

TIA,
-J

Answer (score 1):

Setting the height of the checkbox to 0px seems to fix the issue.  Seems kinda weird, but since it's being hidden by jQuery UI, this is acceptable for now.

```
input[type=checkbox].ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
   height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the overflow and position properties of the #outer div to:

```
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bnT2r/2/)**.